# Axios interceptor - how to return response from vuex store

Tags: typescript, vue.js, axios, vuex, interceptor

I have a login form. When a user enters username/pw the axios interceptor handles the response from the api, whether it's good or bad.

The response is then routed through my vuex store, where user credentials get set.

However, when I console.log the response in my Login component, I don't actually see the fields I need like `data, status, headers` etc.. I see this

[image: response from vuex store after axios interceptor response]

Is there a way I can somehow validate that my data is in the store before proceeding to log the user in?

The only thing I can think of at this point is using a `setTimeout` for a 3 seconds and calling a state getter to retrieve user data.. I mean it works but I am sure there is a more appropriate solution out there

Login.vue

```
onClickLogin() {
    const userToLogin = {
      username: this.loginForm.username,
      password: this.loginForm.password
    };
    const response = UsersModule.login(userToLogin);

    console.log("response", response); // returns what is pictured in the image above so the if block is technically wrong
    if (response) {
      this.$router.push("/");
    }
  }
```

axios request class

```
const service = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_URL,
  timeout: 5000
});

service.interceptors.response.use(
  response => {
    return response.data;
  },
  error => {
    Message({
      message: error.message || "Error",
      type: "error",
      duration: 5 * 1000
    });
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```

vuex users login function

```
  @Action({ rawError: true })
  async login(usersSubmit: UserSubmit) {
    const response: any = await loginUser(usersSubmit);
    if (typeof response !== "undefined") {
      const { accessToken, username, name } = response;

      setToken(accessToken);
      this.SET_TOKEN(accessToken);
      this.SET_USERNAME(username);
      this.SET_NAME(name);
    }
  }
```

api class which calls the axios request from the vuex store

```
export const loginUser = (data: UserSubmit) => {
  return request({
    url: "/auth/login",
    method: "post",
    data
  });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`login` is `async` function, this means that it returns a promise, like the question describes.

Asynchronous control flow and promises in particular are contagious, this requires all callers that rely on it to use promises, too. Notice that `login` doesn't return anything so it cannot resolve to a response:

```
  async onClickLogin() {
    const userToLogin = {
      username: this.loginForm.username,
      password: this.loginForm.password
    };

    try {
      await UsersModule.login(userToLogin);
      this.$router.push("/");
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Login failed');
    }
  }
```

Comment: Don't I need to check what `await login` returns before routing elsewhere? Based on the above code, the await gets called and goes off to do its thing and the `this.$router.push` gets executed immediately. So does it even make sense to await on the login?

Comment: `UsersModule.login` is defined as `async login(usersSubmit: UserSubmit) {`, isn't it? Then it can be seen that it `login` returns a promise of `undefined`, it does all necessary side effects inside and doesn't need to return a result. It rejects with an error if it fails, otherwise it's considered successful. That's why it needs `try..catch`. Not `await`ing for it would result in a wrong behaviour because IIUC a redirect needs to be done after setting a token.